# How to Check my Codeigniter app works when 100 users login at a time?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have created a survey app and its going to launch soon . My client told they are going to send the survey link to 1000 users in a company . The problem is I don't know how to check if 100 or say even 10 users logs in at a time will give any mysql or php errors . is there any tool to simulate this .

Comment: `http://jmeter.apache.org/`

Comment: thanks i will check it and update here , thanks again